# redirect user from sudirectory to main directory

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I need to 301 redirect urls like this:

```
example.com/exam/anything
example.com/anything
```

my current .htaccess file

```
  RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/index.php?$1 [L]
```

i do not know how it work

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^exam/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

Comment: when user access example.com/exam/index.php?market/news_by_cat/top_stories/0/3456 it not redirect to example.com/index.php?market/news_by_cat/top_stories/0/3456

Comment: @AnuragGupta  Please up-vote and accept the answer if helped thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this 1 liner solution:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/exam/(.+)$ /$1
```

If you want to permanently redirect the url, Change 302 to 301 when you are sure the Redirect is working fine.